# Maintaining Relationship Class between Feature Class and Attribute Table after primary key attribute is changed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, file-geodatabase, relationship-class

I have a File Geodatabase Feature Class with Polygon features of agricultural LAND_PARCELS.  Each land parcel has a unique PARCEL_ID.

The land parcel Feature Class needs to be related to a table that will store AGRI_ENVIRONMENT attributes for each land parcel.  The Table has a field for the land PARCEL_ID and additional fields for HABITAT, MANAGEMENT etc.

I created a 1-Many Composite Relationship Class with the LAND_PARCELS feature class as the origin and AGRI_ENVIRONMENT as the destination table.  The Primary Key and Foreign Key fields are PARCEL_ID in both tables.  I called the relationship class MANAGEMENT.

The PARCEL_IDs can change when there has been a physical change on the ground, for example if a land parcel is split in two then two new unique PARCEL_IDs are created, or if a portion of a land parcel is removed from agricultural use then a new PARCEL_ID is created for the new polygon shape.  When the PARCEL_ID is changed in the origin table the Relationship is broken.

Is there a way to update the Foreign Key automatically when a Primary Key is changed?